# python - division and truncation

Tags: python

I run this

```
>>> float(100) / 13000
0.007692307692307693
```

It rounds it

However, in my calculator I get `0.0076923076923077`, which is the answer I want

How can I get this?

Comment: So you want the result rounded to a certain number of decimal points?

Comment: Python is rounding it by itself. I don't want it rounded.

Comment: Your calculator is rounding the number more than Python is.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculator is rounding the result to `16` decimal places.  You can do the same with [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(float(100) / 13000, 16)
0.0076923076923077
>>>
```